# How to update documentation of a cocoapod not hosted in a GitHub repo

Tags: cocoapods

Since [CocoaDocs stopped working](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaDocs-Documentation-Sunsetting/) the documentation of a pod I managed does no longer get updated.

It is a pod that is distributed as zip containing the built framework and a README.md. It does not have a GitHub repo. Is there any way how I can update the documentation that is displayed on cocoapods.org? It gets quite outdated and I did not find anything to update the documentation.

[CocoaPods-Metadata-Service](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-Metadata-Service/) sounds like it could be a solution, but does not look like this is going to be finished soon: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-metadata-service/issues/1

Is there any known workaround - e.g. hosting only the README.md in a GitHub repo? How would that be configured in the podspec file?

example of how the podspec is configured:

```
s.name         = "myLib"
s.version      = "1.2.3.456"
s.summary      = "a little bit of text"
s.homepage     = "https://www.example.com"
s.documentation_url = "https://help.example.com"
s.source       = { :http => "https://example.com/version/myLib_1.2.3.456.zip" }
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publicly host the README and provide a link in the Podspec (https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#readme). This way cocoapods.org will pickup the changes and display your README instead of the provided description. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to achieve this without external hosting anymore.